# Update SOLR document without adding deleted documents

Tags: solr

I'm running a lot of SOLR document updates which results in 100s of thousands of deleted documents and a significant increase in disk usage (100s of Gb).

I'm able to remove all deleted document by doing an optimize

> curl http://localhost:8983/solr/core_name/update?optimize=true

But this takes hours to run and requires a lot of RAM and disk space.

Is there a better way to remove deleted documents from the SOLR index or to update a document without creating a deleted one?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Update: by doing an update with commit=True and expungeDeletes=True on rare occasions it does remove some of the deleted documents that were added (from 8295 without it to 97 with it) but it also significantly increased execution time (from 2min30s to 5mins). This is helpful but I'd prefer to not add those deleted documents to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lucene uses an append only strategy, which means that when a new version of an old document is added, the old document is marked as deleted, and a new one is inserted into the index. This way allows Lucene to avoid rewriting the whole index file as documents are added, at the cost of old documents physically still being present in the index - until a merge or an optimize happens.

When you issue expungeDeletes, you're telling Solr to perform a merge if the number of deleted documents exceed a certain threshold, in effect, meaning that you're forcing an optimize behind the scenes as Solr deems necessary.

How you can work around this depends on more specific information about your use case - in the general case just leaving it to the standard settings for merge factors etc. should be good enough. If you're not seeing any merges, you might have disabled automatic merges from taking place (depending on your index size and seeing hundred of thousands of deleted documents seems extensive for an indexing processing taking 2m30s). In that case make sure to enable it properly and tweak it values again. There's also changes [that were introduced with 7.5 to the TieredMergePolicy](https://lucidworks.com/2018/06/20/solr-and-optimizing-your-index-take-ii/) that allows even more detailed control (and possibly better defaults) for the merge process.

If you're re-indexing your complete dataset each time, indexing to a separate collection/core and then switching an alias over or renaming the core when finished before removing the old dataset is also an option.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I looked into modifying the TieredMergePolicy, in particular the reclaimDeletesWeight parameters but did not figure out how to do so. Do you know how this can be modified? Should it be present in the solorconfig.xml file by default or added to it manually?

Comment: It'll have to be added - see [Customizing Merge Policies](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/indexconfig-in-solrconfig.html#IndexConfiginSolrConfig-CustomizingMergePolicies) for how the section should look. The `reclaimDeletesWeight` setting should be changable through a `<double name="reclaimDeletesWeight">2.0</double>` there. You tell it to use the TMP through `<mergePolicy class="org.apache.lucene.index.TieredMergePolicy">  ... settings .. </mergePolicy>`

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh. I updated my solrconfig.xml file adding `<mergePolicy class="org.apache.lucene.index.TieredMergePolicy">`
      `<int name="maxMergeAtOnce">8</int>` 
      `<int name="segmentsPerTier">8</int>` 
      `<double name="reclaimDeletesWeight">10.0</double>` 
    `</mergePolicy>`. I'll update ~500k documents and see how it looks like tomorrow.

Comment: using reclaimDeletesWeight = 10 did not help. My update resulted in ~500k new deleted documents (~1.5% of the total index size) and ~100Gb index size increase (~30% of the index size). I'm guessing the number of deleted documents is not large enough for the merge to be triggered. How can I check if automatic merges is disabled? When using expungeDeletes, it doesn't seem to be doing a full index optimize. Is that correct? Is there a way to see which index segment has the most deleted documents and only optimize those segments? Thanks again for your help.